# Multiply all permutations of number lists (via using custom function with dynamic arguments)

Tags: python, list

I have a function that has two arguments that are both lists as shown below

```
def myfunc(arg1, arg2):
    return arg1*arg2

arg1 = [1,2,3,4]
arg2 = [10,9,8]
```

I want to return a list of each possible PERMUTATION of the two arguments.

So the result should be something like:

```
[10,9,8,20,18,16.......]
```

I believe this isn't possible with maps and zip as they would return something like:

```
[10,18,24]
```

Is there any easy way to get this done without having to write out the arguments manually?

P.s: I'm using a placeholder function in my example, so i definitely need a way to pass the two lists as arguments

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to pass multiple lists to you function dynamically, you can write custom function using `*args` (Read [Use of *args and **kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3394835/2063361) to know more).

Within your function you can use combination of [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), [`operator.mul()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.mul) and [`functools.reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) (or [`reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) in Python 2.x) within a [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) expression to get the [*cartesian product*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20specifically%20set%20theory,and%20a%20set%20of%20columns.) of your lists as:

```
from itertools import product
from operator import mul

# In Python 3+
# from functools import reduce

def list_multiplication(*args):
     return [reduce(mul, a) for a in product(*args)]
```

Sample Run:

```
# with 2 lists as argument
>>> list_multiplication([1,2,3,4], [10,9,8])
[10, 9, 8, 20, 18, 16, 30, 27, 24, 40, 36, 32]

# with 3 lists as argument
>>> list_multiplication([1,2,3,4], [10,9,8], [7, 8, 9])
[70, 80, 90, 63, 72, 81, 56, 64, 72, 140, 160, 180, 126, 144, 162, 112, 128, 144, 210, 240, 270, 189, 216, 243, 168, 192, 216, 280, 320, 360, 252, 288, 324, 224, 256, 288]
```

Comment: Right, just commented above, the function Im using is actually a lot more complicated than the product function I wrote above. So I would still need a way to pass arguments from two lists that handle each permutation right? I don't believe the options above would be able to do that

Comment: Do you mean that your `list` arguments which you need to pass needs to be dynamic? for example, you want your function call with 2, 3, 4, etc arguments?

Answer (score 1):

Try something which is called **list comprehension**, very useful thing in python!

```
 x=[i*j for i in arg1 for j in arg2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use NumPy ([`numpy.outer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html)):

```
import numpy as np

arg1 = [1,2,3,4]
arg2 = [10,9,8]

np.outer(arg1, arg2).flatten()
#array([10,  9,  8, 20, 18, 16, 30, 27, 24, 40, 36, 32])
```

The method [`numpy.ndarray.flatten`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) is for getting a 1-dimensional output, if you don't use it you'll get a matrix:

```
#np.outer(arg1, arg2)
#array([[10,  9,  8],
#       [20, 18, 16],
#       [30, 27, 24],
#       [40, 36, 32]])
```

Comment: Apologies, the function Im using is a lot more complicated than the product, I just used that to make the question easier to understand, so I essentially need a a way to pass lists as arguments into a function that is fairly complicated. Is there anyway to achieve that?

Comment: @SaadShahid can you be more specific?